# How to find the projection onto a symmetric space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projection

> A square matrix $A$ is symmetric if $A = A^T$ . Let $S$ be the subspace of symmetric matrices, inside the vector space of all $2 × 2$ matrices. Consider the matrix X = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\\ \end{bmatrix} where a, b, c, d are known constants.

> A) Find the orthogonal projection of X onto subspace $S$

> B) Find the orthogonal projection of X onto $S^\perp$

My attempt:
I've never really projected into a **matrix vector subspace**, I've only ever done vectors to vectors, but the steps I think are probably the same.

Finding an orthogonal basis for the subspace of symmetric matrices: $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Here's where things get confusing. I need to find how much of X is in the "direction" of each of my basis matrices, right?

So,

$$Proj(X) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix} X + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt(2)} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt(2)} & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}X + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}X$$.

Where the second matrix is normalized so that it has "length" = 1, is this correct approach?

---

I actually computed it and it didn't seem to work. In the end I got
$$proj(x) = \begin{bmatrix} a + \frac{c}{\sqrt(2)} & b + \frac{d}{\sqrt(2)} \\ \frac{a}{\sqrt(2)} + c & \frac{b}{\sqrt(2)}+ d\\ \end{bmatrix} $$

To get a symmetric matrix, I need the off diagonal terms to be equal. How can I go about finding this projection?

---

For part b, I'm not really sure how to go about finding $S^{\perp}$. If S were spanned by a set of vectors, then I would just need to find the nullspace of S and that would be $S^{\perp}$. How do I go about doing it in this situation where we have a space of matrices?

Comment: Note that it doesn't make sense to find an "orthogonal basis" or "orthogonal projection" in this context unless we have an *inner product* over the space of matrices. You have not yet stated what this inner product is in your context. The usual choice is the "Frobenius inner product", i.e.
$$
\langle A, B \rangle = \operatorname{tr}(A^TB) = \sum_{i,j}a_{ij}b_{ij}.
$$
We can't do anything until you tell us what your inner product is (or confirm that you are using the Frobenius inner product).

Comment: Oops, yes I do mean the Frobenius inner product!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That said, your orthogonal basis is fine, but maybe you can already see what's wrong with your formula for $\operatorname{proj}(X)$. Certainly, we should be using an inner product with $X$ at some point in the formula

Comment: Sorry, I don't really see what's wrong. Did I not multiply the matrices correctly?